# Visual 2012 C++ - the same static lib for debug and release

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, release

Is it possible to create on static library for release and debug project? Unfortunately I need to store some libs in git repository and I want to avoid storing to much binary code in repository.
My idea was to create some universal lib for release and debug, but for now I meet problems related to: "mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0'".

Thanks for any suggestions.

Pawel

Comment: This is a diagnostic that was added in VS2010. It helps you prevent shooting your leg off when you link code that was built with Debug build settings with iterator debugging enabled with code that was built with Release build settings. This causes extraordinarily difficult to debug runtime failure, the STL template classes won't be the same size.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. However I decided to store library code in my repository and it builds depending on mode.